# Azure devops checkmarx periodically scan everything

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, checkmarx

I am trying to user the fullScanCycle parameter for checkmarx in azure devops, but for some reason this is not working.

```
- task: Security static source code analysis@2020
    inputs:
      CheckmarxService: "CheckMarx"
      projectName: "myProjectName"
      preset: "High and Medium"
      fullTeamName: 'someName'
      fullScansScheduled: true
      fullScanCycle: 3
      folderExclusion: "cvs, .svn, .hg , .git"
      fileExtension: |
        ...
      syncMode: true
      vulnerabilityThreshold: true
      high: 1
```

According to me my code should be scanned trice incrementaly and the fourt time full. but this is not happening. I want my code to be scanned again after three times even if the code was not changed. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

you can see these scans only take += 1 minute. a full scan would take over 30..

Answer (score 0):

Checkmarx doesn't invoke the scan if there are no source changes. I believe that actually no scan was triggered at all. You should see that in the logs.